# Android - check if instance of async task is running and cancel it before executing a new one

Tags: android, android-asynctask, cancellation

I have a gridview of bitmaps of very large number. To prevent out of memory error I only load a number of bitmaps and using onScrollListener I recycle the non nessecary bitmaps and create the ones that need to be shown. The loading bitmaps proccess is done in async task. This is the update method which is called every time the scrolling stops

```
AsyncCaller asyncCaller;

public void updateImageList(int first, int last){
        if(!asyncCaller.isCancelled()){asyncCaller.cancel(true);}
        asyncCaller=null;
        asyncCaller=new AsyncCaller();
        asyncInput input=new asyncInput();
        input.first=first;
        input.last=last;
        input.id=Integer.toString(asyncId);
        asyncId++;
        asyncCaller.execute(input);
}
```

where asyncCaller is a class variable.

This code causes a NullPointerException at the asyncCaller.execute(input); line. Can someone tell me why since I assing to asyncCaller a new instance before calling execute?

I used asyncCaller as class variable in order to be able to cancel it if a new scroll has been made before the currently running AsyncTask has finished. No reason to keep it running since those bitmaps are no longer needed.

If I use asyncCaller as a local variable in the updateImageList method there is no way to cancel the currently running instances...correct?

EDIT: the question is pointless since the problem was a simple error from my part. I leave the question with my code corrected and working for refference for anyone looking for something like that

Comment: but but you set asyncCaller to null

Comment: You have assigned null value to it o.O

Answer (score 1):

replace this line

```
asyncCaller.execute(input);
```

with

```
new AsyncCaller().execute(input);
```